# How is it possible thatHttpContext.Current.Session be null in the Application_PostAcquireRequestState event?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm trying to figure out a way to start the MVC Mini Profiler depending on whether one of our developers is logged into our Production website.  We have rolled our own authentication and authorization mechanisms, so I need to be able to inspect the current session to get the ID of the logged in user, and I cannot seem to ascertain where to best do this inspection to know when to call MiniProfiler.Start();.

Much of the time, foo winds up being null in this code sample, though according to the MSDN documentation for this event it doesn't seem like this should ever be possible:

```
protected void Application_PostAcquireRequestState()
{
    var foo = HttpContext.Current.Session;
}
```

This application is using the MVC2 framework.

How can this ever be null?  Also, does anyone have any good recommendations where I should start the profiler?  My next guess is going to be whatever "begin request" events are available in our controller base class.

Comment: I've found that adding a simple null check for Session fixes my problem.  If Session is not null, I check to see the ID of the person logged in and it all works.  However, I'll let my question stand because I am not certain how it is possible for this to be occurring.  I'm guessing that perhaps my browser is not submitting an ASP.NET_SessionID cookie for one of the various requests it performs to load a page.

Comment: Inspecting HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl shows me that the only time that Session is null is when the miniprofiler results themselves are being requested, such as here: /mini-profiler-results?id=db19bd6c-9bbf-4a4b-9714-00fe68eba513&popup=1 and here
/mini-profiler-results?id=31d0bb70-5bda-43af-8234-7d22afd6fa08&popup=1  Obviously part of the request processing pipeline is being bypassed.  Can anyone offer any insights?